# ReactJS error You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using facebook [create react app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to build my first web application.

I am trying to load js components like Nav.js, Hero.js, and About.js and import them into index.js.

My Github Repo: https://github.com/brandonpowell/main-kdrusha-website

**The problem:** You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

```
webpackHotDevClient.js:233 Error in ./components/About.js
Module parse failed: /Users/brandonpowell/Desktop/main-kdrusha-website/components/About.js Unexpected token (6:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:6)
 @ ./src/index.js 41:13-43
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import  configureStore  from '../src/soundcloud/stores/configureStore';
import * as actions from '../src/soundcloud/actions';
import Stream from '../src/soundcloud/components/Stream'; // This are the Tracks that render
import Nav from '../components/Nav';
import Hero from '../components/Hero';
import About from '../components/About';

export const tracks = [
  {
    title: 'Some track'
  },
  {
    title: 'Some other track'
  }
];

const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(actions.setTracks(tracks));// This is store the information to the Tracks

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <Hero />
        <About />
        <Provider store={store}> <Stream /> </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'))
```

**Nav.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Nav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
         <nav>
            <div className="logo"></div>

            <div className="social-media-icons">
               <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
               <li><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
               <li><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
               <li><i class="fa fa-spotify" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
               <li><i class="fa fa-soundcloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
               <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
               <li><i class="fa fa-apple" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
            </div>
         </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

**Hero.js**

```
import React from 'react';


export default class Hero extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="welcome-title">Official Website For</div>
            <div className="artist-name">KD Rusha</div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**About.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
         <section className="aboutartist col-inline">
            <div className="imageHere"></div>

            <article className="bio">
              <div className="bioTitle">Biography</div>
              <div className="line"></div>
              <p>KD Rusha is a hip hop artist from San Diego, California. At the age of 17, KD found his knack for music and began to make songs as a hobby. As the year 2012 progressed into 2013, KD found the hobby to become a passion. He released his first project, "Vengeance", in 2012 and it was a little known project that sprawled his high school campus with decent reception.</p>
              <p>Later that year, he released "Throwback", a mixtape that reached the internet with open arms with the major records being "Never Felt the Pain" and "You Already Know" both of which were produced by T-Customz. In 2013, KD saw a growth in his fanbase when he released his next project, "Livelihood". This was the mark of KD finding his own style of music rather than copying his inspirations.</p>
              <p>On December 28, 2013, he released his biggest song to date, "One of These Days" which met the internet as well as the local San Diego </p>
            </article>
         </section>

         <div className="gallery-section col-inline">
            <div className="titlebox">
                <div className="titlegalleryleft">Gallery</div>
                <div className="titlegalleryright">All Images</div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a detail on how you are bundling your React files? Are you using webpack? What does your webpack file look like?

Comment: This is some kind of tutorial? Please give the link. The problem is probably with webpack.

Comment: Can you run `node -v` and give me the output of terminal .. thank you

Comment: @bl4ckdu5t I have update posted

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI node v7.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your components directory inside your src directory and it would be fine. This is weird because it shouldn't happen on a webpack setup however it has been an [issue with creact-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/637#issuecomment-275513687). You should also not be placing part of the source outside of the src.

### Solution

Move `components` directory to `src` and reference the files in your index.js like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import  configureStore  from './soundcloud/stores/configureStore';
import * as actions from './soundcloud/actions';
import Stream from './soundcloud/components/Stream'; // This are the Tracks that render
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import Hero from './components/Hero';
import About from './components/About';
```

notice I also modified the path to the soundcloud directory. You don't need to go a directory backward then back in to reference it.

Also if you are running your server (`yarn start` or `npm start`) when you make this fix, you should stop it and restart it else you'd get a Module not found error.

Answer (score 0):

You have components folder in wrong place of the project. Move your components folder inside src folder and change path form `'../components/Nav'` to  `'./components/Nav'` (form ../ to ./).

Comment: When I remove the one dot it said that Module not found: ./components/Nav

Comment: Also move your components folder inside src folder.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

- change app.js to app.jsx
- test: /.(js|jsx)$/
- "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).